# MSVC++ says the stack around a variable is getting corrupted but program works

Tags: c++, runtime-error, visual-c++-2010, stack-corruption

Sorry if this sounds like an "It compiles, so it must work!" question, but I want to understand why something is happening (or not happening, as the case may be).

In Project Settings, I set `Basic Runtime Checks` to `Both`. The debugger informs me that:

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'beg' was corrupted.

But if I set it to the default, which is none, the program runs and completes normally, throwing no exceptions and causing no errors.

My question is, can I safely ignore this (because MSVC++ could be somehow wrong) or is this a real problem? I don't see how the program can continue successfully when the stack has been screwed up.

---

Edit:

The function that causes this error looks exactly like this:

```
int fun(list<int>::iterator&, const list<int>::iterator&);

int foo(list<int>& l) {
    list<int>::iterator beg = l.begin();
    list<int>::iterator end = l.end();
    return fun(beg, end);
}
```

`fun` increments and operates on `beg` and when it returns, `beg == end`, and when MSVC++ breaks, it points to the closing `}`.

---

Edit 2:

I have isolated the problem. In some situations, `fun` removes some elements from the `list` who owns the items it iterates. This is what causes the error.

Comment: @SethCarnegie let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1994/discussion-between-merlyn-morgan-graham-and-seth-carnegie)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question isn't answerable without code to reproduce the problem.

But to give a vague answer to your general problem - If the compiler or debugger detected a problem, you probably have one.

In C++, just because something "goes wrong" doesn't mean your program will crash - it might keep running with completely unpredictable results.  It may even complete with the results you desired.  But just because it ran well on your system doesn't give you any guarantee for other systems, compilers, times of day, or even for additional runs of the same program.

This is called [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and is caused by using the language incorrectly (but not in a way that causes a compile failure).  A buffer overrun is only one of dozens of examples.

Comment: see if the additional info in my edit helps at all - if not, say so and I'll try to provide more.

Comment: @Seth: The thing to do would be to add a tiny amount of code that demonstrates the problem (maybe not your real code), and add an answer to your own question that shows *why* that is causing a problem.  My answer doesn't really answer your specific question...

Comment: I have a function that calls a function and passes a parameter by reference. I print the address of the variable before and after the function call, and right before the function returns. The address of the variable is the same just as the function is about to return as it is before it was called, but when it returns and I print the address again, the address is off by _one byte_. This **only happens** when I have Basic Runtime Checks set to check stack frames. How is this possible?

Comment: What. What. What........ I didn't do anything. Nothing. And it stopped happening.

Comment: Turns out commenting/uncommenting a print statement will cause it to work/crash. This is dumb.

Comment: @Seth: Without a code sample that repros the problem on its own, I can make no comments besides my original answer :)  You're probably invoking undefined behavior, and just don't know where.

Comment: it's a large program, and I don't know where the undefined behaviour is. Which is why I haven't provided a code sample that causes the problem. Is there any tools that could help me find the source of the problem that you know of?

Comment: @Seth: Start a new project and paste the code you get the error on.  Keep adding supporting code until it compiles.  See if you get the error.  If you don't, keep adding more of the code that gets executed, until you get the error.  Rinse, repeat.

Comment: @Seth: Since it turned out you didn't have a code error, and reinstalling VS solved your problem, you might want to add your own answer and accept it.  Whether I helped troubleshoot or not, this was not the correct answer :)

Answer (score 1):

It turned out something was wrong with my Visual Studio installation, so reinstalling it fixed the problem.